# The alert pop up window does not closing

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am quite new to flutter. I have added navigation for the button inside the alert. But it is not working.
Anyone can tell me what is wrong in that please ....

```
Alert(
      context: context,
      title: "Thank You!",
      desc:
          "Your inquiry has been sent",
      image: Image.asset("assets/success.png"),
      buttons: [
         DialogButton(
              child: Text( "Okay",
                    style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize:20),
              ),
         onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                       builder:(BuildContext context) =>support())),
         width: 120,
   )
  ],
  ).show();
```

Comment: can you also add how are you calling this alert box??

Comment: It is inside an if condition

Comment: can you add the code?? using Navigator.push() there??

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the [rflutter_alert](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert) package based on the widget and method name (it would be best to add this important detail to the question).

If that's the case, make sure that you are calling the `Alert().show()` method from a Widget that is a descendant of the `MaterialApp`. Since it uses [`showGeneralDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/showGeneralDialog.html) under the hood the same rules apply, so that means it needs to be able to access a Navigator.

### Example solution

Many more solutions will work, this is only one of them.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: PopupWidget()),
    );
  }
}

class PopupWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Basic Alert'),
              onPressed: () => _onBasicAlertPressed(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onBasicAlertPressed(context) {
    Alert(
      context: context,
      title: "Thank You!",
      desc: "Your inquiry has been sent",
      image: Image.asset("assets/success.png"),
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "Okay",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Page2())),
          width: 120,
        )
      ],
    ).show();
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Other page')));
  }
}
```